# I do not get all the rows marked, only marks one for some reason,

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
C1_arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
C2_arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
C3_arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  
for eachOne in C1_arr:
    if C1.rows[eachOne]:
        hServicesUsed.rows[eachOne].val = True
        break
for eachOne in C2_arr:
    if C2.rows[eachOne]:
        hServicesUsed.rows[eachOne] = 1
        break
for eachOne in C3_arr:
    if C3.rows[eachOne]:
        hServicesUsed.rows[eachOne] = 1
        break
```

this is supposed to mark all the answers that are selected in rows, but the rows start with similar indexes from 1 to lets say 16 and the other questions from 1 to 7

Comment: The `break` statement stops the loop after it finds one match.  If you want the loop to keep going, why do you have that?